# Problemas con el uso max luego de count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subconsultas

Estimados,
tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as cantidad_respuestas
            FROM encuesta e 
            LEFT JOIN dimension d on e.id_encuesta = d.id_encuesta_p
            LEFT JOIN preguntas p on d.id_dimension = p.id_dimension_p
            LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta_tr 
            LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo_r
            LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno 
            WHERE (f.cod_curso_alumno = '367845' or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL) 
            AND (d.id_dimension = '1')
            GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo
```

que me arroja esta tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente aplicar un max al cantidad_respuesta para me arrojara los máximo de cada id, pero me arroja solo el máximo de las que es 4 y la tabla me debería arrojar es esta

```
id_pregunta  TIPO    CANTIDAD_RESPUESTAS
---------- --------  ------------------
1            4               3
2            5               4
```

Ese es el resultado que necesito, cualquier orientación o ayuda sera de gran ayuda

Answer (score 3):

Usa tu consulta como subconsulta, de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT id_pregunta, tipo, max(cantidad_respuesta) as cantidad_respuesta FROM (
    SELECT p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo, COUNT(r.id_respuesta) as 
    cantidad_respuestas
    FROM encuesta e 
    LEFT JOIN dimension d on e.id_encuesta = d.id_encuesta_p
    LEFT JOIN preguntas p on d.id_dimension = p.id_dimension_p
    LEFT JOIN tipo_respuesta tr on p.id_pregunta = tr.id_pregunta_tr 
    LEFT JOIN respuesta r on tr.id_tipo = r.id_tipo_r
    LEFT JOIN form_alumnos f on r.id_form_alumno_fk = f.id_form_alumno 
    WHERE (f.cod_curso_alumno = '367845' or cod_curso_alumno IS NULL) 
            AND (d.id_dimension = '1')
            GROUP BY p.id_pregunta, tr.tipo
) WHERE cantidad_respuesta <> 0 GROUP BY tipo;
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola folivaresrios. La idea es buena, y por los votos, parece que varios están de acuerdo. Pero en realidad esta consulta no va a producir el resultado deseado, porque haces un `group by` por `tipo`, no por `id_pregunta`. Además, estás cayendo en la trampa típica con MySQL de incluir columnas en el `SELECT` que no están en el `GROUP BY`. Para esas columnas, no hay garantía de qué valor devolverá MySQL. En realidad, la consulta que se necesita es un poco más complicada.

Comment: Te dejo un [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b861/2) para que veas el resultado de la consulta.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces deberías probar con un subSelect en el FROM como si fueras hacer un UNION, te dejo el [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d9149/1)

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo con @folivaresrios que, de una forma u otra, necesitas usar tu consulta actual como subconsulta.  Pero obtener el resultado que deseas no es tan sencillo como parece.

Si el resultado deseado fuera solamente:

```
id_pregunta  CANTIDAD_RESPUESTAS
----------   -------------------
1                   3
2                   4
```

...entonces sería sencillo. Solo se necesitaría un `GROUP BY` + `MAX`:

```
select id_pregunta, max(CANTIDAD_RESPUESTAS)
from (
    -- aquí pones tu consulta actual
) t
group by id_pregunta
order by id_pregunta
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b861/4)</kbd>

Pero tu resultado necesita incluir *todas las columnas* (o sea la columna `tipo` también) del registro cuyo valor para `cantidad_respuestas` es el mayor para el agrupamiento de `id_pregunta`. Esa es la parte incómoda.

Muchas estarían tentados de simplemente agregar la columna `tipo` al `SELECT`, lo que MySQL acepta sin quejarse en versiones anteriores a 5.7:

```
select id_pregunta, tipo, max(CANTIDAD_RESPUESTAS)
from (
    -- aquí pones tu consulta actual
) t
group by id_pregunta
order by id_pregunta
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b861/5)</kbd>

...pero aunque esto es algo que se ve comúnmente, es un error. Como puedes ver en el Fiddle, el valor para `tipo` es incorrecto.

En realidad, [la documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) especifica que incluir una columna en el `SELECT` que no sea usada por una función de agregación (como `MAX`, o `SUM`) y que no forma parte del `GROUP BY`  produce un resultado que no se puede predecir (Cita en inglés: *the values chosen are **indeterminate***).

### Solución

Usualmente, la forma de resolver este tipo de consultas es usando la función ventana `ROW_NUMBER()`, que muchas bases de datos incluyen. Pero MySQL no tiene funciones ventana.

Debido a esto, la única solución realmente correcta es la siguiente:

```
select id_pregunta, min(tipo) as tipo, cantidad_respuestas
  from (
      -- aquí pones tu consulta actual
  ) t
 where (id_pregunta, cantidad_respuestas) in (
    select id_pregunta, max(cantidad_respuestas)
    from (
       -- aquí también repites tu consulta actual
    ) t2
    group by id_pregunta)
group by id_pregunta, cantidad_respuestas
order by id_pregunta
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b861/11)</kbd>

... pero como puedes ver, aunque la consulta produce el resultado correcto, es sumamente ineficiente, porque te obliga a repetir tu consulta complicada 2 veces. Además, la consulta está obligada a definir un `GROUP BY` adicional para eliminar los registros duplicados cuando más de un registro tiene la misma cantidad máxima de respuestas.

Existe otra alternativa que es mucho más eficiente, que usa variables para simular una función ventana:

```
set @rnk := 0;
set @id_pregunta := -1;
select id_pregunta,
       tipo,
       cantidad_respuestas
  from (select tipo,
               cantidad_respuestas,
               @rnk := case when @id_pregunta = id_pregunta then @rnk + 1 else 1 end as rnk,
               @id_pregunta := id_pregunta as id_pregunta
          from (
                 -- aquí pones tu consulta actual
                 -- Importante: también debes agregar este ORDER BY aquí
                 order by p.id_pregunta, cantidad_respuestas desc, tr.tipo
               ) t
        ) t
 where rnk = 1
 order by id_pregunta;
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b861/15)</kbd>

Si usas esta consulta, fíjate bien que a tu consulta original le debes agregar un `ORDER BY` cuando la agregues como subconsulta.

Ahora bien, es importante mencionar que esta consulta depende de que MySQL evalúe las expresiones con variables en el orden que aparecen en el `SELECT`. Según la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), esto no está garantizado (Cita en inglés: *the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is **undefined***). En la práctica, parece que las variables sí son evaluadas en orden. Pero quién sabe si este comportamiento no vaya a cambiar en una versión futura de MySQL. De modo que si prefieres evitar este riesgo, te sugiero usar la primera opción que es menos eficiente, pero con resultados correctos garantizados.